# Good idiom to filter out members of an object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to remove certain members of an object (for the sake of argument, those whose keys start with '_'). What's an elegant way to do this? The naïve way would be:

```
for (var i in obj) 
  if (i[0] === '_') 
    delete obj[i];
```

but that modifies the underlying object during the iteration. In Node at least I guess I could

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (i) { if (i[0] === '_') delete obj[i]; });
```

or restart the iteration each time something's deleted with an awkward nested loop.

Are there any better solutions?

EDIT: In testing just now, in node.js at least, the naïve solution actually seems to work. It certainly is possible that for...in is (required to be) implemented safely. Anyone know?

Comment: Does the modification of the object during the `for ... in` loop cause a problem? I don't see how it's much different from modifying the object in the `forEach()` callback, after all.

Comment: I'm presuming that `Object.keys` takes a snapshot of the keys in the object. Maybe that's not true.

Comment: ...and presuming that `for (... in ...)` doesn't take a snapshot of the object.

Comment: Ah sorry; I see what you mean now.  I'm still not sure `for ... in` would fail in this case but it's an interesting question.

Comment: You can use JSON.parse & JSON.stringify with a replacer function, like `function ( key, value ) { return ( key[0] == "_" ) ? undefined : value; }` .
This will only work with JSON serializable elements

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do not need to worry about it. An excerpt for [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) §12.6.4 explicitly states (emphasised by me):

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the
>   first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.
>   **Properties of the object being enumerated may be deleted during enumeration. If a property that has not yet been visited during
>   enumeration is deleted, then it will not be visited.** If new
>   properties are added to the object being enumerated during
>   enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be
>   visited in the active enumeration. A property name must not be visited
>   more than once in any enumeration.

Comment: -1 - "If a property that has not yet been visited during enumeration" - I think that's not the case here.

Comment: @thejh, then preceding sentense applies. `for..in` is completely safe for property deletion as per standard.

Answer (score 4):

why not create a list of the names to remove like

```
var l = [];
for (var i in obj) 
  if (i[0] === '_') 
    l.push(i);
l.forEach(function(v){ delete obj[v]; });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(function (v) {
    return v[0] === "_";
}).forEach(function (v) {
    delete obj[v];
});
```

This will modify the object during a loop though ;p

If you use this more than once the generic is:

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(function (v) {
    //filter the object values/keys by some conditions
}).forEach( del.bind(obj) );

function del (v) {
    delete this[v];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create a function returning a filtered object. I would prefer this solution in order to avoid collateral effects on other parts of the code holding a reference to the object being modified.

```
function filterObject(obj) {
  var filtered = new Object();
  for (var i in obj)
    if (i[0] != '_')
      filtered[i] = obj[i];
    return filtered;
}
```